# ExpandableListView child item's CheckBox gets checked randomly

Tags: android, android-layout, expandablelistview

I created an ExpandableListView with a quite complex child item xml. It contains a TextView, a Checkbox and an EditText.
Here is the CheckBox part:

```
 <TableLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
               android:layout_width="match_parent"
               android:layout_height="55dip"
               android:orientation="horizontal"
               android:stretchColumns="0">
  <TableRow>
  android:layout_width="fill_parent"
  android:layout_height="wrap_content"
  android:orientation="horizontal"
  >
  <TextView
      android:id="@+id/lblListItem"
      android:layout_width="wrap_content"
      android:layout_height="wrap_content"
      android:textSize="14dip"
      android:paddingTop="2dp"
      android:paddingBottom="2dp"
      android:paddingLeft="?android:attr/expandableListPreferredChildPaddingLeft"/>
  <CheckBox
      android:id="@+id/cboxIsRel"
      android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content">

  </CheckBox>
  </TableRow>
  </TableLayout>
```

If I check the 1st item, in every group the 5th item is also gets checked (if the 2nd is selected, then the 6th gets selected).

Why do they get also selected?

**UPDATE:**

In the `getChildView` method I have this code:

```
if (convertView == null)
{
  LayoutInflater infalInflater = (LayoutInflater) this.context.getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
  convertView = infalInflater.inflate(R.layout.expandable_list_item, null);
}
TextView txtListChild = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.lblListItem);
txtListChild.setText(childText);
```

If I don't use the convertView check, then the checkbox isn't reused but also the selected checkbox gets unselected if I scroll out.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It's because of recycling of the views.

Make sure that on your adapter, the bindView() or getView() methods sets the checkbox as checked or not.

Edit:

ListView reuses the views to improve performance, so In your case the 1st item is checked, then the same view is used on the 5th child, so its why it is also checked.

So to prevent this from happening, you must save which position is checked and on your getChildView() method you should check/uncheck your checkbox based on the saved value.

This way, you check the 1st item, then you scroll and the view is recycled to the 5th child, the adapter will call getChildView for position 5 and you will check if it was checked. Since it's not checked, you call setchecked(false) on the checkbox and it will appear unchecked.

Comment: I don't quite understand your proposal. In the adapter I have a getChildView but it doesn't set anything of the checkbox's state. Can you explain a little more?

Comment: Am I responsible to save the checked state of my checkboxes? Say, in a HashMap? Isn't there any built-in support for that?

Comment: Well, that's why the listview needs an adapter. The adapter is a representation of your data to display. As you can see the checkbox keeps it's state, that's why you have the problem. I don't understand why you don't save this information already, you can't depend on your activity to remain on memory forever, you need to save your data to return to last state when the activity is destroyed.

Comment: Thanks for the explanation. I'll save the states and restore them.